# Detect collisions for each instantiated objects

Tags: unity

I want to instantiate cube at a random position when I click mouse and do something (change color or freeze position ..) for each cube when detect collision on the plane.

I tried first few steps:

```
public Rigidbody cube;

void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.name == "Plane")
    {
        //Do somthing for each cube
        cube.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints.FreezePositionY;
    }
}

void Update()
{
    Vector3 position = new Vector3(Random.Range(-5f, 5f), 8,Random.Range(-5, 5));

    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        Rigidbody clone;
        clone = Instantiate(cube,position, Quaternion.identity);
    }
}
```

Comment: How did the results of your first few steps above differ from what you want? What specific problem can we help you solve?

Comment: @DMGregory In my code when the first cube hit on the plane and detect collision all other cubes stop moving. I want to freeze each cube that touch the ground separately